# Android IndexOutOfBoundsException in version 5.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, indexoutofboundsexception

My application has problems every time when a user tries to access an item in a list. This problem is happening only on devices with version 5.1 (Xperia Z2 (D6503), Z3 Compact Xperia (D5803))

The application has been tested and runs well on versions (4.1) (4.4) (2.3.3), (2.3.7), (4.0.3), (4.0.4)

The error report says:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15324)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4114)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14257)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14217)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14217)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14217)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14217)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14252)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14252)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14252)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14252)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14252)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15049)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15324)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2653)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14257)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14279)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2540)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I cannot understand completely which part of the source code has the problem. So I don't know which part of the code must be  posted here. Sometimes, the first time when the user press the element list works fine, but then appears the error and does not allow access again.

The following code shows how the user accesses the list item:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                int position, long id) {

                itemList currentlog = (itemList )parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                sendToFragmentInterface(currentlog.getUserId());
                MyLogs.clear();
        }
    });
```

On this occasion, a fragment with the user profile detail opens. However, you can access the same fragment from the main menu and runs fine. It seems... only when you try to access from a list, the application crashes.

This is the interface:

```
public interface openUserProfile {
    public void getUserProfile(String user_id);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (activity instanceof openUserProfile ) {
        listener = (openUserProfile ) activity;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implemenet MyListFragment.interfazCambiaFragment");
    }
}

public void sendToFragmentInterface(String user_id) {

    listener.getUserProfile(user_id);
}
```

This is the code "getUserProfile" in the MainActivity that hold the call and opens the fragment:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Fragment fragment = new UserProfile();

    args.putString("user_id",user_id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    setTitle("Profile");
```

The application has been tested and runs well on versions (4.1) (4.4) (2.3.3), (2.3.7), (4.0.3), (4.0.4) ...Can anyone tell me what happens?

Comment: The error is at `HeaderViewListAdapter:164`. Can you post this code?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan i dont have any Header Adapter in my fragment. Only this line inside OnCreate:
        'header = ((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header_profile, null);'

Comment: Sure, my bad, didn't see the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing it for a while, I realized that the line mylogs.clear() which cleaned the list after using it, was the one that caused the error. I had put it there because I thought I could save memory. Android versions higher than 5.0 do not support this.